# Need support to design database

Tags: database, database-design

Case: A system for small groups and clubs is to be set up online.  Each of the clubs simply has a name and a number of members.

There are several types of membership.  It is possible to join simply as a normal member, or you could be a president, secretary or any other member type.

One person can be a member of many different clubs, and have different membership types with each.

I need to design a simple database to hold the information relating to the clubs, users and the memberships held.

In order to have a normalised database, I have three tables - club, membership and members.
club - id, name
membership - id, name (normal, president, secretary, etc)
members - id, name, contactinfo, membership_id

I am not able sure how to make relation between these tables!

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]?  Which RDBMS are you using?  Also, if this is homework it should be tagged with [tag:homework].

Comment: This is not a homework! I am working on a application on following platforms: ios, php, asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a table similar to

```
users_clubs:

uc_id | club_id | user_id | membership_id
```

Comment: I thought about doing this before but I was confused regarding the relationship between the tables. I am not good in defining relations! So, I am still confused...

Comment: `users_clubs.club_id` relates to `clubs.id`, `users_clubs.user_id` relates to `users.id`, `users_clubs.membership_id` relates to `memberships.id`,

Comment: Yeah, I got that thanks! But the thing I am not able to understand is - can we have any relation between club, membership, members table if if don't create the users_clubs table. Means any other way?

Comment: No. Since it is a many-to-many relationship, you need many rows for each club and many rows for each user - thus no possibility to put them in one of the existing tables (without **really** ugly hacking)

Comment: I am going to use your table for relation. Thanks for your time mate! :D